# How to format Date and Time to display in All Caps?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, date-time, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 17, with the Cinnamon desktop environment. I was hoping there was some way to format the Date and Time to display the Month (abbreviated) and the Day of the week (abbreviated) in all capitals.

Specifically, this is desired for the “Calendar Panel Applet,” but I wouldn't mind it being global on the system.

The appropriate parameters should be `%^a` and `%^b`, but all that this causes is a clock format error. So much for using proper syntax.

I’ve also gone into the `locales/en_US.con`f (my locale) file and changed the Unicode for `LC_TIME` to be the uppercase equivalent for the abbreviated values (for all 12 months and all 7 days), but this hasn't changed a thing anywhere.

I have regenerated and rebooted since this change as well, to make sure it took effect. No dice.

It isn’t absolutely necessary, and I can just get used to it. What I won't do is just say “I give up. Nix the idea…” without putting in a reasonable effort to figure out how to do it. Because I’d prefer it with that format, and I’ll likely learn something from the process even if unsuccessful at my goal.

Is there a relatively “pain free” way to accomplish this?

I’d happily delve into the appropriate source code and recompile and so forth if I knew where that was and how to do it without breaking anything; haven’t changed the source on a compiled and running system file before.

I’d probably be willing to delve any depths that don’t require any extra installs, and even in that case I may be willing.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal:

```
$ date +'%^a, %d %^b %Y'
SUN, 22 MAR 2015

$ date +'%a, %d %b %Y'
Sun, 22 Mar 2015
```

*prepend a null LC_TIME as in `LC_TIME= date ...` to have it show in English/Default locale*

Might it be "the desktop" trims off the `^` character from the definition?
Is it possible to prepend an escape character, say that you enter `\^` for each `^` you wish to insert.

Comment: `date +'%^a, %d %^b %Y'` works on Linux, not on BSD tough. On Unix use `date +'%a, %d %b %Y' | tr -s '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`